# Custom DataGridViewColumn with different Value and Display

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a custom `DataGridViewColumn` that allow user to input a value like `1:30`.

If the user saves it to the `Database`, I have a function to store it as Decimal Value so the for 1:30 will become 1.5. The Database Column is a `float`.

Now, my problem is that the cell is not accepting when I enter a time Format like 1:30. after the cell lost focus the values disappears. So is it possible to display a string format (1:30) in  a cell with a typeof double? How? Can you show me some code to do it? Thanks.

Code for Custom `DataGridViewColumn`:

```
public class OptTimeColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
   public OptTimeColumn() : base(new OptTimeCell())
   {

   }

  public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
  {
     get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
     set
        {
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(OptTimeCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a OptTimeCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class OptTimeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public OptTimeCell() : base() 
    {
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        OptTimeColumnEditingControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as OptTimeColumnEditingControl;

        OptTimeColumn col = (OptTimeColumn)this.OwningColumn;

        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            ctl.DecimalValue = Convert.ToDouble(this.DefaultNewRowValue);
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.DecimalValue = Convert.ToDouble(this.Value);
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(OptTimeColumnEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            //return typeof(string);
            return typeof(double);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            //return string.Empty;
            return DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}
public class OptTimeColumnEditingControl : OptTime.OptTime, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public OptTimeColumnEditingControl()
    {

    }
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DecimalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.DecimalValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                }
                catch
                {
                    this.DecimalValue = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    }
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
    }
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnTextChanged(eventargs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your example code so we can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I modified above and I added the code for Custom DataGridViewColumn.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorry to ask like this but: `Why-oh-why are you saving time to db as double?` Does not your db support Time or DateTime datatypes?
2. What kind of method are you using to interface with db - ORM, like EF? Something else? It is generally very bad to have direct dependency of UI on storage, or storage on UI. Use some layer(s) between. Ideally explore MVC, MVVM and DI/IoC.
3. To achieve what you want, for example in EF, you can take advantage of the built in ViewModel pattern, where  you can transform the data to your liking, before serialization or after deserialization. View (Grid) should be set to datatype you want the user to see, e.g. "Time", and your storage type should be set to what you prefer to store, e.g. "VARCHAR(32)" - then the logic you implement in ViewModel would need to effect (hopefully lossless) conversion between the two.